# Microsoft Teams bot - debug link unfurling

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to implement pretty simple teams bot but constantly facing an issues with unpredictable behavior. E.g. [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/link-unfurling?tabs=dotnet#handle-the-composeextensionquerylink-invoke) clearly says that Teams applies Adaptive card as link unfurling response but when I'm sending pretty simple response like:

```
var card = new AdaptiveCard(new AdaptiveSchemaVersion(1, 0));
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock { Text = "Title", Size = AdaptiveTextSize.ExtraLarge });
var attachment = new MessagingExtensionAttachment { ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType, Content = card };
var result = new MessagingExtensionResult(AttachmentLayoutTypes.List, "result", new[] { attachment });
return new MessagingExtensionResponse(result);
```

Teams doesn't render anything or follback to the default behavior.
So the question is - are there any way to debug why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one easy way to find out what's going on and if your part is generally ok is by sending a full "static" card as a test. Just create the JSON layout somewhere, load it and sent it unchanged to MS Teams.

Also creating AdaptiveCard's like that is not the best way to do it, have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/ its a lot easier to handle cards like that.

Specific to your question there's no real way to debug anything inside ms teams. You can get a few errors in the analytics part of the bot framework and some times console output of your browser gives a few hints.

I wrote a similar thing some time ago which inserts a card on specific links similar to what you're trying to do and generally, that was (and still is) working fine.

Comment: Running in browser I found the error: {"errorCode":1008,"message":"<BotError>Error when processing invoke response: Attachment content is empty or invalid format"}
but is still unclear what exactly is wrong.
Also I replaced card with json layout which is pretty small:
{ "type": "AdaptiveCard",  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [ { "type": "TextBlock", "size": "extraLarge", "text": "Title" } ]
}

Comment: In general you are right the best (= the only) way to see any errors is to use browser version of Microsoft Teams. Particular in my case the problem is that I have no ideas how to use Attachment and Preview fields of MessagingExtensionAttachment for unfurling response. It looks like Preview field overrides Attachment but I still have to clue how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, the problem is this is not documented at all. You'll need to send a hero card (maybe something else works as well?) as preview and the adaptive card as full card:

```
return {
        composeExtension: {
            type: 'result',
            attachmentLayout: 'list',
            attachments: [{
                preview: CardFactory.heroCard("title", "description")
                ...CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)
            }]
        }
    };
```

This will display an "expandable" hero card which resolves to the adaptive card.

Comment: This works for me, but why? Why it must use hero card as preview? Is it a bug? Any one knows?

Comment: @YitongFeng: It is a known bug with adaptive card.

Comment: @SubbaReddiTummuru - We have a similar functionality and trying to avoid having hero card as preview.
Is there a logged bug for this. Can you please share a link for the same.

Comment: @Naina: In Desktop, I see adaptive card is showing in preview. So, hero card is not required now.
But in mobile, card is showing in expandable view to see the adaptive card.