# What is the correct way to return an AdaptiveCard from a Message Extension?

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Environment: Node JS v10.15.3, botbuilder v4.7.2, adaptive cards v2.5

From within handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery, I can pass back a simple Hero Card and it displays just fine but I'm stumped on getting an Adaptive Card passed back. Here is the code:

```
        const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
            {
               "type": "TextBlock",
               "text": "This is an adaptive card"
            }
        ],
        "actions": [
            {
               "type": "Action.Submit",
               "title": "OK"
            }
        ]
      });
    const preview = CardFactory.thumbnailCard("Thumbnail card", ['https://www.dropbox.com/s/jb5nhnkla12dcj4/wi-day-lightning.png?dl=1']);

    return {
        composeExtension: {
            type: 'result',
            attachmentLayout: 'list',
            attachments: [{ ...card, preview }]
        }
    };
}
```

This will display the thumbnail card but not the adaptive card.  I checked SO prior to posting this and the only posting that talks about this is this one:
[How to use Adaptive Cards on Teams Messaging Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116935/how-to-use-adaptive-cards-on-teams-messaging-extension)
Unfortunately, I can't get that code to even run so I'm stumped.

Any guidance would be very welcome.
(P.S. - there are no examples on MS or adaptivecards.io that cover this case as far as I can see)

Regards,
ac

Answer (score 2):

So I've answered my own question.  The code above works just fine.  What I didn't know, because the docs don't tell you, is that Teams initially displays the preview card (which, in my case is a thumbnail card). Tap on the thumbnail to render the adaptive card and place it into the message stream.

All along, I was trying, and expecting, to see the adaptive card displayed as the initial display. Thanks to @mnkypete for providing that critical piece of information in this post: [Microsoft Teams bot - debug link unfurling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232439/microsoft-teams-bot-debug-link-unfurling)

ac

Comment: do you actually *need* a thumbnail? If you don't want your user to see it, just don't send it (send only the adaptive card)...

Comment: The code as I have it does not work if I only send an adaptive card.  Without the preview card, I get an "Unable to reach app. Please try again" message...
If you have working code that only sends an adaptive card, please share...

Comment: @AndrewCoad- This is updated in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/respond-to-search?tabs=dotnet#response-card-types-and-previews).